# same table on different commands (inner join)

Tags: mysql, join

Testing some commands of MySQL, I've come across these two comands resulting on the same table.

Command 1:

```
select sales.relatory_code, sales.date, destiny.exportation_name from sales, destiny where sales.destiny_exportation_code = destiny.destiny_exportation_code;
```

Command 2:

```
select sales.relatory_code, sales.date, destiny.exportation_name from sales inner join destiny on sales.destiny_exportation_code = destiny.destiny_exportation_code;
```

Basically, instead of using two tables on "from" clause and using the "where" clause, i'm just using "inner join". I would like to know what's the main difference between the two commands and if one is better than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command 1 is the SQL-89 standard for joining between tables.

Command 2 is the correct method of writing JOINs as per the ANSI-92 SQL standard (yes, that is 92 as in 1992). Some 23 years later and people still don't want to conform to ANSI-join standards.

Theoretically, there is no difference between the two in terms of performance, it's apparently just a hard habit for people to break and some find it more readable if they're used to writing queries in that way.

There's a few more reasons for why people use the old standard as opposed to the new one in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334201/why-isnt-sql-ansi-92-standard-better-adopted-over-ansi-89).

I also seemingly keep referring back to [Aaron Bertrand's posts](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) (even though this one is written about SQL Server). This one may give you some more information on why you should be using the ANSI-92 Standard style joins.

Comment: I totally agree that it's better to use the new style (and certainly don't mix the two) but the old-style is still valid SQL, according to the SQL-92 standard. Even according to SQL-2011 standard. It's not wrong per se.